# How to have a wsdl conform to the soap input

Tags: soap, wsdl, jax-ws

We are changing our soap webservices from jetty to jaxws. The goal is to keep the same input message. I have used the original WSDL to create the service with netbeans. The WSDL is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://www.mycompany.nl/DcxExpeditieService/v1"
        xmlns:tns="http://www.mycompany.nl/DcxExpeditieService/v1"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.mycompany.nl/DcxExpeditieService/v1"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
            <xs:element name="DcxExpeditie" type="tns:DcxExpeditie"/>
            <xs:complexType name="DcxExpeditie">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Expeditie" type="tns:Expeditie"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="Expeditie">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="tag1" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="tag2" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="DcxExpeditieRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="DcxExpeditie" type="tns:DcxExpeditie"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="DcxExpeditieResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="DcxExpeditieResponse" type="xs:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="DcxExpeditieServicePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="DcxExpeditieOperation">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:DcxExpeditieRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:DcxExpeditieResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="DcxExpeditieServiceSOAP" type="tns:DcxExpeditieServicePortType">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="DcxExpeditieOperation">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.mycompany.nl/DcxExpeditieService/v1/DcxExpeditie"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://www.mycompany.nl/DcxExpeditieService/v1"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://www.mycompany.nl/DcxExpeditieService/v1"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="DcxExpeditieService">
        <wsdl:port name="DcxExpeditieServiceSOAP" binding="tns:DcxExpeditieServiceSOAP">
            <soap:address location="https://someserver.mycompany.nl/vbs/dcxexpeditie"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

When using this WSDL in soapui it results in the following input example:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://www.mycompany.nl/DcxExpeditieService/v1">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:DcxExpeditieOperation>
         <DcxExpeditie>
            <v1:Expeditie>
               <v1:tag1>?</v1:tag1>
               <v1:tag2>?</v1:tag2>
            </v1:Expeditie>
         </DcxExpeditie>
      </v1:DcxExpeditieOperation>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

However, the original input format was:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://www.mycompany.nl/DcxExpeditieService/v1">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <v1:DcxExpeditie>
                <v1:Expeditie>
                   <v1:tag1>?</v1:tag1>
                   <v1:tag2>?</v1:tag2>
                </v1:Expeditie>
          </v1:DcxExpeditie>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

so with no `DcxExpeditieOperation` tag and with the `v1` namespace in front of `DcxExpeditie`

Is this possible and if so, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change SOAP binding from rpc to document to remove DcxExpeditieOperation tag:

```
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
```

To fix the namespace issue refer DcxExpeditie element insted of type:

```
<wsdl:part name="DcxExpeditie" element="tns:DcxExpeditie"/>
```

Updated WSDL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://www.mycompany.nl/DcxExpeditieService/v1"
                  xmlns:tns="http://www.mycompany.nl/DcxExpeditieService/v1"
                  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.mycompany.nl/DcxExpeditieService/v1"
                           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
            <xs:element name="DcxExpeditie" type="tns:DcxExpeditie"/>
            <xs:element name="DcxExpeditieResponse" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:complexType name="DcxExpeditie">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Expeditie" type="tns:Expeditie"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="Expeditie">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="tag1" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="tag2" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="DcxExpeditieRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="DcxExpeditie" element="tns:DcxExpeditie"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="DcxExpeditieResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="DcxExpeditieResponse" element="tns:DcxExpeditieResponse" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="DcxExpeditieServicePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="DcxExpeditieOperation">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:DcxExpeditieRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:DcxExpeditieResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="DcxExpeditieServiceSOAP" type="tns:DcxExpeditieServicePortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="DcxExpeditieOperation">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.mycompany.nl/DcxExpeditieService/v1/DcxExpeditie"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="DcxExpeditieService">
        <wsdl:port name="DcxExpeditieServiceSOAP" binding="tns:DcxExpeditieServiceSOAP">
            <soap:address location="https://someserver.mycompany.nl/vbs/dcxexpeditie"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: If i change the binding to document netbeans says: There is no service in specified WSDL file

Comment: I made couple of fixes and updated answer with WSDL file. Could you please check, if it  will be imported?